# React testing library, how to test history.push

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

In a React App, I have a button that goes to a new url programatically:

```
<ComposeButton
  onClick={() => {
    history.push('some-link'))
  }}
>
```

In my test, I render my component as mentioned in the react-testing-library documentation for [React Router](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-router/):

```
const renderComponent = (page: Pages) => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory()

  return renderWithState(
    <MockedProvider
      mocks={mocks}
      addTypename={false}
      defaultOptions={{
        watchQuery: { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' },
        query: { fetchPolicy: 'no-cache' }
      }}
    >
      <Router history={history}>
        <ComponentToRender />
      </Router>
    </MockedProvider>
  )
}
```

How can I wait for this change page in react-testing-library?

```
it('sends invitations', async () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByTestId, debug, getByText } = renderComponent(
      Pages.contacts
    )

    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve))

    const writeMessageBtn = getByTestId('write-message-btn')
    waitFor(() => fireEvent.click(writeMessageBtn))
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve))

    waitFor(() => debug()) // <- expect to see new page

    getByText('EV_305_NEW_INVITATION_SEND') // <- this is in the second page, never get here
})
```

I can never see the content of the new page (after clicking the button) when using `debug`

Comment: are you rendering your component in the test inside a `Router` with a defined route for 'some-link'?

Comment: I add the `Router` to the test, but still test does not wait for new page content.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will make everything work, but there are a few issues with the code sample you shared I can highlight:

1. You are rendering a `Router` but no `Routes`. Use [MemoryRouter](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/MemoryRouter) instead and provide the same routes as your actual application - at least provide the route you are pushing into history
2. You are not using `react-testing-library` correctly. Instead of using `getByTestId`, use `findByTestId`.  e.g. `const writeMessageBtn = await findByTestId('write-message-btn')`. The difference is that `get*` queries are synchronous while `find*` are async. You don't need to wait for arbitrary timeouts, the testing library will try to find the element for a few seconds.
   The same applies to the other places where you use `get*`

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't use get*?

Comment: @BastianStein I expanded my answer a little, for more details I suggest you read the docs of `react-testing-library`

Comment: I understand that get is synchronous. In a test, why would i want to use the async version, in cases where I'm awaiting the result anyways?

Comment: The test might cause a change in the UI you want to wait for. Best to wait for the UI change instead of a timeout or promise because these might end before the UI had a chance to update

Comment: i understand now, thanks. i had the misconception that get will block for a certain time, until it can find the element, or fail. but that is not the case.